# I can't seem to center this table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm trying to get this table to be centered but whenever I view the page, it shows up aligned to the left.

CSS

```
.center {

    margin-left:auto; 
    margin-right:auto;
  }
#hor-minimalist-a
{
  font-family: "Segoe UI", Frutiger, "Frutiger Linotype", "Dejavu Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  background: transparent;
  margin: 45px;
  width: 480px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1.6em;
}
#hor-minimalist-a th
{
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #039;
  padding: 10px 8px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #6678b1;
}
#hor-minimalist-a td
{
  color: #669;
  padding: 9px 8px 0px 8px;
}
```

and here is the html that I am using to test:

```
<table class="center" id="hor-minimalist-a" >
   All of the table data goes here
</table>
```

Comment: To center with margins. It must have a fixed width.

Comment: @John That's only true for block elements.  Tables center just fine with auto margins.

Comment: @John The table does have a width of 480px...

Answer (score 3):

The problem is one of specificity in your CSS rules:

```
.center {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
#hor-minimalist-a {
    font-family:"Segoe UI", Frutiger, "Frutiger Linotype", "Dejavu Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    background: transparent;
    /* margin: 45px; */
    width: 480px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1.6em;
    border: 1px dashed blue;
}
```

In your CSS, you have set `margin: 45px` in your `#hor-minimalist-a` rule, which has a higher specificity than your `.center` class which has your left/right margin rule.

If you comment out the `margin: 45px` rule, your table centers.

See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/JxMD3/

**Note: Using margins to center tables**
As pointed out in one of the comments, using margin left/right of auto will center the table even if you don't specify the width (that is, use `width: auto`).
Reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#width-layout

**Note: About specificity**
For details about how specificity works, see: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity

Answer (score 0):

This should remove "margin: 45px" from the following rule:

```
    #hor-minimalist-a
    {
      font-family: "Segoe UI", Frutiger, "Frutiger Linotype", "Dejavu Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;
      font-size: 16px;
      background: transparent;
      margin: 45px;
      width: 480px;
      border-collapse: collapse;
      text-align: center;
      line-height: 1.6em;
    }
```